# In-memory cache for saving strings or NSNumbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching

Is there any external library out there that does in-memory caching? I was just thinking of creating a `NSDictionary` with key-value stores for this if there isn't any. I know there's `EGOCache` but this does disk caching. Any ideas?

Comment: You can always use a memory-mapped SQLite table.  (Though it's not clear what you expect your "in-memory cache" to do that NS(Mutable)Dictionary doesn't.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "caching" functionality you want? Size limit? Sensitivity to memory conditions? Time-based expiration of contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is basically like an NSDictionary with a few modifications to let you purge data based on priority etc.